# Acceder a un valor de una propiedad de un objeto a json PHP

Tags: php

Buenos días tengo un objeto (viene de aqui $respuesta = $this->autor_model->getAutor();)

```
      {
           "titulo": "Este es un artículo",
           "visitas": 345,
           "publicado": true,
           "categoria": null,
           "comentarios": 
            {
                  "autor": "Luisa López",
                  "mensaje": "Muy buen artículo"
             },
            "estado":
            {
                  "codigo": "200",
                  "mensaje": "ok"
            }

       }
```

Estoy intentando acceder al valor de autor, de la siguiente forma

```
 $respuesta = $this->autor_model->getAutor();       
        
 
 $response_json = json_encode($respuesta, true);        
   
 $response = $response_json->{'autor'};
 print_r($response);
```

Me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at parse (<anonymous>)
at jquery.min.js:2:79369
at l (jquery.min.js:2:79486)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2:82254)
```

Mi pregunta es como acceder al valor de autor? ya que necesito emplearlo más adelante, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida

Comment: No entiendo porque intentas manipular un json en PHP, la función [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) te devolvera un `string` en formato json del valor (`mixed`) que deseas parsear. Por otro lado no se que valor exacto está retornando tu metodo `$this->autor_model->getAutor();`

Comment: mi método está retornando esa respuesta json que vemos al principio que comienza con  ("titulo": "Este es un artículo"), viene en formato json porque es una respuesta de un curl que ejecuto

Comment: Entonces lo que necesitas es usar la función [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) al cual le pasaras un `string` en formato json y te devolvera un `array` asociativo con el resultado parseado, eso en caso de que marques el segundo parametro como `true`

Comment: me puedes orientar como hacerlo?

Comment: Ya agrego una respuesta

Comment: gracias aguardo la respuesta

Comment: Por cierto, creo que deberias editar y mejorar la redacción de tu pregunta, estoy casi seguro que tu código **PHP** está dando un error fatal en tiempo de ejecución y lo que colocas alli es un error de **Javascript**. Deberias colocar el error de **PHP**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien, si lo que obtienes a través del método `$this->autor_model->getAutor();` es un string en formato **json**, lo que debes hacer es usar la función [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) de **PHP** como ya habia dicho en los comentarios.

Tienes dos opciones para parsear el json a un valor aceptable de **PHP**, parsearlo a un **object** o a un **array asociativo**.

Por ejemplo:

1. Como objeto:

```php
<?php

// Forzamos el valor a solo string
$res = (string) $this->autor_model->getAutor();

// Lo pasamos a un objeto de PHP
$object = json_decode($res);

print_r($object->titulo);
```

2. Como array asociativo:

```php
// Forzamos el valor a solo string
$res = (string) $this->autor_model->getAutor();

// Lo pasamos a un array de PHP
$array = json_decode($res, true);

print_r($array['titulo']);
```

---

##### Nota extra: ¿Que sucede con las claves complejas como por ejemplo `user-id` o `pestaña`? cuando parseamos a un objeto y no a un array

A modo de suposición (ya que no estoy seguro) **PHP** crea un objeto que gracias a la [**Overloading**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.overloading.php) permite acceder a los valores del objeto, cuando se usa `json_decode()` con su parámetro `associative` como `null` o `false`

Cuando una clave tiene un nombre complejo como por ejemplo `user-id`, no podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```php
<?php

$object->user-id;
```

Ya que **PHP** nos arrojará un error de sintaxis. ¿Como se hace en este caso? sencillo

Este maravilloso lenguaje de programación nos permite acceder a propiedades de los objetos de manera dinámica, usando un string como clave

De la siguiente forma:

```php
<?php

$object->{'user-id'};
```

Lo cual funcionara a la perfección

Answer (score 1):

Debes usar la función **json_decode()** y así podrás acceder a lo que necesitas.

Así se obtiene un objeto stdClass.

```
    $json = '
    {
       "titulo": "Este es un artículo",
       "visitas": 345,
       "publicado": true,
       "categoria": null,
       "comentarios":
        {
              "autor": "Luisa López",
              "mensaje": "Muy buen artículo"
         },
        "estado":
        {
              "codigo": "200",
              "mensaje": "ok"
        }

   }';

// Así se obtiene un objeto stdClass.
$r1 = json_decode($json);
echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($r1);
echo '</pre>';
echo 'Autor es: '.$r1->comentarios->autor; //Autor es: Luisa López
```

Así se obtiene un Array Asociativo. Colocando el valor **true** como segundo parámetro.

```
    $json = '
    {
       "titulo": "Este es un artículo",
       "visitas": 345,
       "publicado": true,
       "categoria": null,
       "comentarios":
        {
              "autor": "Luisa López",
              "mensaje": "Muy buen artículo"
         },
        "estado":
        {
              "codigo": "200",
              "mensaje": "ok"
        }

   }';

// Así se obtiene un Array Asociativo.
$r2 = json_decode($json, true);
echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($r2);
echo '</pre>';
echo 'Autor es: '.$r2['comentarios']['autor']; //Autor es: Luisa López
```

Como tu has solicitado el valor de **autor**, y ese valor se encuentra en los "comentarios del articulo" que trae el json se debe acceder hasta ese valor respetando la jerarquía y estructura de json en cuestión.

Puedes aprender mas en [este articulo](https://diego.com.es/introduccion-a-json-en-php).